# Где меняется надпись Recurring Мероприятие в календаре мероприятий WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, геолокация

Есть сайт на WordPress, на который установил плагин календаря мероприятий [The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/the-events-calendar). Добавил периодически повторяющиеся мероприятия, и теперь на странице под заголовком фигурирует надпись **Recurring Мероприятие (Посмотреть все)**

и всплывающая подсказка:
*An event every 1 day(s) that lasts day(s) and hour(s), the last of which will begin on*

Где можно поменять текст на русский или удалить вовсе? Облазил уже весь плагин, в файле локализации, искал по классам тегов - все тщетно, никак найти не могу. Запостил в гугл - такая бяка не только у меня одного вылазит.

Comment: ссылку поправьте

Comment: @artoodetoo уже

Comment: А можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: @Валерий Емельянов зачем? вбейте фразу в гугл - там много таких сайтов для ознакомления

Comment: Не нашёл, Вам помощь нужна или нет?

Comment: @Валерий Емельянов да, нужна - пусть будет вот этот (здесь все аналогично): http://englishpark.bkc.ru/events/2015-07-28/

Comment: Обязательно удалять или достаточно будет скрыть?

Comment: @Валерий Емельянов обязательно. скрыть - это дело 5 минут, но мы же с вами стремимся быть не горе специалистами, верно?)